# Can I turn my Android tv box into a NAS server?

Tags: android-tv, web-server

I've got a MXQ Pro 4k TV Box and a 4TB hard drive that I rarely use and I was wondering if there was any software I can use to make it a server.

The MXQ box has 1GB RAM, a 2.0GHz quadcore chip and ethernet, usb and hdmi ports.

Do you think it would be easier for me to put linux on the box and run it from there? Also would there be a way for me to set up a segment of this drive as a time capsule?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

It'll surely be easier if you set up a GNU/Linux system on the box.

There's a very popular NAS software on Linux named "samba", and is available everywhere from built-in repositories, i.e. you can install it with `sudo apt-get install samba` or `sudo yum install samba`. Bunches of tutorials about it are available on the Internet. However that good job does not have an Android port :)

For setting up Apple Time Capsule, I used to learn that it's possible but I don't know if it's still possible now. You should search online instead of asking here – it's blatantly off-topic on **Android** Stack Exchange. Maybe you want to ask on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)?